# How can I check if request was a POST or GET request in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, request, http-post, http-get

I just wondered if there is a very easy way to determine whether the request is a `$_POST` or a `$_GET` request.

So does `Codeigniter` have something like this?

```
$this->container->isGet();
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I've never used codeigniter, but for this I check the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`.

Looking at [the docs](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/input.html) maybe something like:

```
if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') === 'GET') {
   //its a get
} elseif ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') === 'POST') {
   //its a post
}
```

If you're going to use it a lot then it's simple to roll your own `isGet()` function for it.

Comment: It works, but it is not the way to do this for CI; see input->method().

Answer (score 12):

For CodeIgniter 3 users: [the docs state](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/input.html#CI_Input::method) the input class has a function to get the request method:

```
echo $this->input->method(TRUE); // Outputs: POST
echo $this->input->method(FALSE); // Outputs: post
echo $this->input->method(); // Outputs: post
```

Comment: Your doc link is out of date since CI4 was released: [new link](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/input.html#CI_Input::method)

Comment: updated link https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/input.html#CI_Input::method
replace *user_guide* to *userguide3*

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is:

```
if ($this->input->post()) {
   //have post
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In codeigniter 4:

```
$this->request->getMethod() // Returns get, post, or whatever the method is
```